# How to change the vscode status bar colour back to its default colour?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As you can see the colour of status bar and the title bar has turned to Reddish-Brown.
I haven't made any changes and it automatically got changed.
How to I bring it back to its **DEFAULT MODE**.

[image]

My settings.json file

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a workspace? If so, maybe there is a `.vscode/settings.json` file in the workspace containing the color settings?

Comment: I have added the contents of my settings.json file in the questions>
It doesn't seem to have any colour settings.

Comment: Please note that there is a [difference between your global settings file and a workspace settings file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations). Have you checked both? Also, please [don't post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3018229).

Comment: these are all comments to the question

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences -> Color Theme and select one of the standard VS code themes (Dark, Dark+, Light, Light+).

Comment: I have tried this
But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the [Window Colors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stuart.unique-window-colors) extension installed? If so, try disabling it.

Comment: I don't have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution lies in Workbench Color Customizations section. I opened the JSON file and saw two lines "activityBar.background" and "titleBar.activeBackground" assigned that same reddish brown color. I deleted both and title bar + activity bar colors were restored.

Answer (score 0):

I used the peacock extension and messed up the colors. The fix was to delete `settings.json` from `.vscode` in my project and everything was revert to default colors.